# Задача с классами python

Tags: python, алгоритм, ооп

Помогите пожалуйста правильно и тщательно составить комментарий о коде, для дискуссии с преподавателем (что за что отвечает, почему это пишется сюда). Тобишь просто "объяснить" код.

Cоздайте класс Die с одним атрибутом sides, который имеет значение по умолчанию 6.
Напишите метод roll_over() для вывода случайного числа от 1 до количества граней на кубике.

Создайте экземпляр,представляющий 6-гранный кубик, и смоделируйте 10 бросков.
Создайте экземпляры, представляющие 10 и 20 гранный кубик.
Смоделируйте 10 бросков каждого кубика.

```py
from random import randint  

class Die():  
    def __init__(self, sides=6):  
        self.sides = sides  

    def roll_die(self):  
        return randint(1, self.sides)  


def model_roll(die,n=10): 
    print(f'Кубик {die.sides} граней') 
    for i in range(n): 
        print(die.roll_die()) 

model_roll(Die()) 
model_roll(Die(10)) 
model_roll(Die(20))
```

Comment: Вы этот код сами написали?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению

Comment: А в чем именно заключается задача, и откуда вы взяли данный код? Вам преподаватель дал код, чтобы вы разобрались или как?

Comment: А текст задания точно такой? Просто если класс должен имитировать игральный кубик, то логично было бы, чтобы он назывался Dice, а не Die

Comment: Преподаватель дал код, чтобы мы с ним завтра поговорили насчет него - что за что отвечает, почему было выбрано это и так далее. Сказал сделать полный комментарий к нему.

Текст задания точно такой.

Comment: @Xander Нет, там оказалось что нет опечатки, слово Die это форма единственного числа слова Dice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
# Импортируем функцию randint из модуля random, чтобы генерировать ЦЕЛЫЕ случайные числа
from random import randint  

# Определяем класс "Die" (кубик)
class Die():  
    # Конструктор класса, где можно задать количество граней (по умолчанию 6)
    def __init__(self, sides=6):  
        # Устанавливаем количество граней кубика как атрибут объекта, 6 по умолчанию
        self.sides = sides  

    # Метод для броска кубика
    def roll_die(self):  
        # Генерируем случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до количества граней и возвращаем его
        return randint(1, self.sides)  

# Функция для моделирования бросков кубика
def model_roll(die, n=10): 
    # Выводим сообщение о количестве граней кубика
    print(f'Кубик {die.sides} граней') 
    # Бросаем кубик n раз (10 раз по умолчанию)
    for i in range(n): 
        # Выводим результат броска на экран
        print(die.roll_die()) 

# Создаем и бросаем кубики с разным количеством граней
model_roll(Die())  # Бросаем кубик с 6 гранями 10 раз
model_roll(Die(10))  # Бросаем кубик с 10 гранями 10 раз
model_roll(Die(20))  # Бросаем кубик с 20 гранями 10 раз
```